# Go workspace vs custom folder structure

Tags: go

I'm currently learning Go, and I have learned that Go suggests (expects? enforces?) that you use a specific folder layout for your workspace:

```
- my-go-workspace
  - src
  - bin
  - pkg
```

I perfectly understand the reasoning for this, and I definitely see its advantages. So, basically, I think it's a good thing to have a structure like this.

The only thing I don't like about this, is that it is a completely different structure from my other projects. E.g., for my Node.js projects there is a folder such as this:

```
- projects
  - moduleA
  - moduleB
  - ...
```

Now if I want to keep Node.js modules and Go packages side-by-side, in a unified folder structure I either have to use Go's way for Node.js as well (which feels wrong), or vice-versa (which feels wrong either).

I guess it's probably a dumb idea, and I should simply stick with Go's suggestion and live with two different ways of organizing my code (hey, it's different languages, why should the folder layout be the same?), but somehow this does not feel clean to me.

I know that this a highly subjective and personal, but my question is, if there are any practices out there on how to solve this? Or should I just live with it?

Comment: If you follow the path of least resistance, you have fewer things to fight while you're learning and you'll have a better time.  Do it the easy way, have just one workspace, and things get much better:  https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more simple idea:

```
golos-projects
 L node-project-a
    L what
    L ever
    L yolo
 L node-project-b
    L we
    L love
    L npm
 L go-project-a
    L src
    L pkg
    L bin
 L go-project-b
    L src
    L pkg
    L bin
```

And just set your `GOPATH` to e.g. `golos-projects/go-project-b` and hack away. When you want to switch to another project just change your `GOPATH` to the new project's folder.

Comment: A nice idea as well :-). Are there any downsides in having multiple workspaces in Go?

Comment: Not at all, that is the intended workflow, actually.

Comment: The downside is that you're spending a bunch of effort trying to keep up with lots of workspaces instead of just learning go.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the structure you want, as long as `$GOPATH` references a [workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) which follows the convention

```
my-go-workspace
  - src
  - bin
  - pkg
```

In your case, `src/` could simply be a symlink to `projects/` (located anywhere else), in which you would have Node and Go projects.

Comment: The idea with the symlink is great, thanks for that :-)